# Trying to SSH into an ubuntu server using global IP

Tags: server, ssh, ip, port-forwarding

I've set up an ubuntu server, and can SSH into it just fine via 192.168.1.20. However, attempting to use the global IP results in SSH hanging. I've forwarded port 22, and confirmed that that is the port SSH is listening on.

Comment: If you do `ssh -v ` etc, where does it get stuck?

Comment: @serverstreambox Are you trying to connect to your public IP from INSIDE your network? If so, unless your router knows how to handle that traffic, it will not work. Try tethering your phone to your laptop/desktop (disconnecting from your network first). Once you are outside your internal network, test your port forward again.

Comment: I tried using my vpn to next outside the network, but it hangs all the same.

it hangs at 

OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to *ip*[*ip*] port 22.

Comment: @Jos @ G Trawo s

Comment: Thanks to nmap, I've figured out that my port forwarding isn't working. I'm trying to fix that